# Are nedarim considered Biblical or Rabbinic laws?

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, derabanan, deorayta

If you make a neder (a personal vow), is following it considered a matter of Biblical (d'oraysa) or Rabbinical (d'rabbanan) law? Please bring sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the circumstances. Obviously, *n'darim* in general are a matter of biblical law: they're mentioned in the *Tora*. [*Yad*, *N'darim* 1:4.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=5462) On the other hand, some rules were established by the rabbis as safeguards against violating biblical laws of *n'darim*. [Ibid., :27.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=5485)